# How to set persistent storage for curl cookies?

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

```
self.c.setopt(self.c.COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt')
```

However, the file is not created. What I want is to store and read cookies from file so they can be persistent after application restarts.

Does it have anything to do with COOKIEJAR option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [COOKIEFILE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEFILE) is the file to use as source of cookies for a session, [COOKIEJAR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEFILE) is the file where cookies from the session should be stored.

```
self.c.setopt(self.c.COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt')
self.c.setopt(self.c.COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt')
```

Notice that (depending on how your script is used) a relative path to the cookie file might give you unexpected results.

Comment: This doesn't create cookie.txt file, even if I specify absolute path like `c:\\cookie.txt`.

Comment: Does the server send cookies? Check the notes on debugging in the COOKIEJAR documentation.

Comment: Yes, I can see in Fiddler the cookies are sent using `Set-Cookie`.

Comment: Moreover, enabling VERBOSE mode for curl I can see in the log `* Added cookie` right when data is received. Also cookies are send for subsequent redirection which means they are stored internally in curl but not in the file object.

Comment: According to the documentation, the cookie file is written when `curl_easy_cleanup` is called - do you call `self.c.close()`?

Comment: It worked, but this is odd, becaues the doc says `This method is automatically called by pycurl when a Curl object no longer has any references to it, but can also be called explicitly.`. Anyway, thanks a lot!